# Splitting a string to all it's characters

Tags: google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula

This should have been simple but I can't find a workaround. I want to split a string into its characters.
e.g. dog will be sepearted to:
d
o
g

The problem is I can't put an empty character as a delimiter in the SPLIT function.
What am I missing?

Comment: The following link includes some answers that might indicate how to do this: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/51648/how-automatically-to-add-spaces-inbetween-each-character-in-a-text-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
=split(regexreplace(A2, "(.)", "$1_"), "_")
```

or if you'd want an arrayformula to process a column at once

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(A2:A), split(regexreplace(A2:A, "(.)", "$1_"), "_"),))
```

[image]

[image]

### Reference

More info on how this works? Check [this link.](https://regex101.com/r/I3NPOU/1)

Comment: This is great, thanks. Can you please explain how this works?

Comment: The regexreplace adds an underscore after every character (that's what the dot means in regular expression). Correcter: it replaces every character with the same character with an added underscore. Then, split is used (with the underscore as delimiter) to create the array of separate characters.

Comment: Also added some additional info in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, so (.) represents a character, and $1_ represents adding _ to the character? 
Why $1 and not (.)_ ? This looks more intuitive

Comment: Regular expressions have a specific syntax. To learn more about that syntax, check this link: https://support.google.com/a/answer/1371415?hl=en

Answer (score 8):

Also

```
=ArrayFormula(mid(A1,sequence(1,len(A1)),1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
=SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(O13,"(.)","$1"&"-"),"-",1,1)
```

[image]